# WinCE 6.0, work with GPRS/WiFi

Tags: c#, windows-ce, wifi, gprs

I'm working on a project, which should connect to servers through wifi/gprs. Project is an application for Windows CE 6.0 device, I'm writing in Visual Studio 2008 on C#.

I have two severs to work with. The first I have to connect via wifi, second - via gprs. So I need to know, how can I change the method of connecting between wifi and gprs?

I found and tried this way: I turn on both wifi and gprs on my device. So I work via wifi because it has a higher priority. When I need to work via gprs, I turn off wifi (`SetDevicePower` function). But when I turn wifi on, it doesn't connect back to my Preferred Network.

Also I heard about the way to change priority between gprs/wifi in OS priority table programmatically, but I didn't find any information about how to do this.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the route command from a shell.

lets assume

```
server1 ip: 123.123.123.1
server2 ip: 123.123.123.2

wifi ip   : 192.168.1.101
   gateway: 192.168.1.1

gprs ip   : 10.1.2.3
   gateway: 10.1.1.1
```

Now you can excute in a command prompt

```
route add 123.123.123.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1
```

and

```
route add: 123.123.123.2 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.1.1.1
```

This should route all trafic to server 1 over wifi and to server 2 over gprs, without changing a single line of code in your app.

You can verify it worked with

```
tracert 123.123.123.1
tracert 123.123.123.2
```

However, you could use your app to periodically perform this task (I assume gprs ip could change from time to time) with Process.Start(...)

```
- delete route 1
- add route 1
- delete route 2
- add route 2
```

You even could specify the interface with the `IF 2` switch (route list prints the interface id for your network cards).

Another interesting post to read is this one: http://ce4all.blogspot.com/2007/05/routing-ip-traffic-via-specified.html

The author uses the GetAdapterAddresses() and CreateIpForwardEntry() P/Invokes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927384.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee495149%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx

Comment: I tried this way. `GetAdapterAddresses()` works properly, so I've got WiFi and GPRS IP. But I don't understand how to use CreateIpForwardEntry()`. Where can I get data for `dwForwardNextHop` and `dwForwardIfIndex`. Also where can I get gateway for wifi and gprs?